# Fibonacci numeration system

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

> Instead of binary or decimal, the Kingdom of Leutonia uses an unusual system to represent numbers, based on the Fibonacci sequence. The Fibonacci sequence $F_0,F_1,F_2,\dots$ is defined recursively as follows 
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> F_0&=1\\
> F_1&=1\\
> F_n&=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\text{ for }n\ge 2
> \end{align*}
> $$
>   A Leutonian number is a string of 0’s and 1’s that begins with a 1 and never has two
>   consecutive 1’s. If $s=s_\ell s_{\ell-1}\dots s_1$ is such a string of length $\ell$, where each $s_i$ is in $\{0,1\}$, the
>   number represented by $s$ is $n(s)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\ell s_i\cdot F_i$.
>
> For example, $n(1000101)=F_7+F_3+F_1=21+3+1=25$.
>
> (a) Write out the Leutonian numbers that represent the first 12 positive integers.
>
> (b) Prove: For every $\ell\ge1$, if $s$ is a Leutonian number of lenght $\ell$, $n(s)\ge F_\ell$

[image]

I am trying to do (b).

That's what I did:

Basis: $p(1) : \sum_{i=1}^1 s_i \cdot F_1 \ge F_1$

$ = \sum_{i=1}^1 s_1 \cdot 1 \ge 1$

Since a leutonian number must starts with 1. $s_1 = 1$

so the base case is true.

I can't do the induction case.

Comment: This is just a thought, have you tried looking at a Leutonian number of length $L\gt2$ as a combination of a length $L-1$ and length $L-2$ Leutonian numbers and using the Fibanocci recurrence to do the induction case?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Zeckendorf's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem). See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198253/every-natural-number-can-be-written-as-the-sum-of-distinct-fibonacci-numbers/198284#198284

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you could also have added link to the original source: http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2014-15/F/2001/a2.pdf (Google does not return many hits for "Leutonian numbers", so I guess this might be where the problem comes from.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you want to use induction to prove this. Can't you say that a Leutonian number $s$ of length $l$ has $s_l=1$, hence $s=\sum_{i=1}^ls_iF_i=F_l+\sum_{i=1}^{l-1}s_iF_i\geq F_l$, since each term $>0$?