# Fibonacci's decomposition

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've read somewhere that every natural $n$ can be expressed using only Fibonacci's numbers which index is superior or equel to $2$. For example
$$
25=F_{8}+F_{4}+F_{2}
$$

I wonder if there exists a proof of this statement because I have no clue about it. Maybe an induction ?

Comment: In fact, you can even do it with non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers.  See, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198253/every-natural-number-can-be-written-as-the-sum-of-distinct-fibonacci-numbers)

Comment: This is Zeckendorf's theorem and the proof essentially uses greedy algorithm.