# Every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

Let $(F_n)$ be the Fibonacci numbers ,defined by $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ where $F_0=0, F_1=1$

My attempt:

Let $F_k$ be the biggest Fibonacci number, such that $F_k \leq n$ still holds.
Now we consider $n-F_{k_1}$. We know that $n-F_{k_1}< F_{k_1}$. Now lets assume $F_{k_2}$ is the smallest number such that $F_{k_2} \leq n- F_{k_1}$
Now consider $n-F_{k_1}-F_{k_2}$ ...

Therefore I tried to do

Induction:
Let's assume every number up to $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as a sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers.
We want to show that this holds for $n+1$:
Let $F_k$ be the smallest Fibonacci number such that $F_k < n+1$.

Then $n+1- F_k \leq n$, this means that $n+1- F_k:=m$ can be written as a sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers $m=F_{l_1}+...+F_{l_i}$.
But since $n+1-F_k=m \leq F_k$, there can't be $i$ such that $F_{l_i}=F_k$.
Thus $n+1=m+F_k=F_{l_1}+...+F_{l_i}+ F_k$ is a sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers.

Question:
I am not really sure if my solution is correct, so is it correct? Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/198253/42969, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem

Comment: You have to be a bit careful about your base case. Consider your argument for $n=2$. As written, $1$ is the only nonzero Fibonacci number less than it and $2-1=1$ so you seem to get $2=1+1$ which is not a sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @podiki Thanks, it should have been $\leq$

Comment: @podiki I did edit it